# I have changed my gitlab default url from 127.0.0.1 but upload artifacts still posts to it

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am playing with doxygen CI/CD integration on my local (only for testing) GitLab CE instance. Initially, I have configured it to be 127.0.0.1 but I forgot that containers would have their own localhosts so I changed to the actual IP address. The problem I have is that when the worker tries to upload artefacts, it still tries to access the 127.0.0.1 address instead of the given one. Do you know where I should change it? I have searched the configuration files but found nothing.

```
$ mv ../documentation/html/ public/
Uploading artifacts for successful job 00:05
Uploading artifacts...
public: found 3002 matching artifact files and directories 
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... error  error=couldn't execute POST against http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/75/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive: Post "http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/75/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused id=75 token=64_Aus-U
```

Answer (score 1):

Runner configuration was not changed. I needed to change it in the config.toml file